# Get value of several CheckButtons with same variable name tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function which creates a dictionary depending on the file the user put in parameter.

And then I create a GUI which create as many CheckButtons as there are elements in dictionary.

Here is my code :

```
for element in self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams :
    self.diagramVar = IntVar()
    self.diagram = Checkbutton(self.window, text=element, variable=self.diagramVar, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    self.diagram.pack(side = BOTTOM)
self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
self.validate.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

The problem is i can't access to the state of a specific checkbutton as they have all same variable name.

And I don't know how can I name them differently.

I tried to create variable name with dictionary element's name with `setattr(self, element, 0)` or with `exec` but it doesn't worked because `str(element)` can be very long.

How can i do this ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A very simple fix to this would be to use a list, and just add each `Checkbutton` to the list.

For example:

```py
self.diagramVars = []

for element in self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams :
    diagramVar = IntVar()
    diagram = Checkbutton(self.window, text=element, variable=diagramVar, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    diagram.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    self.diagramVars.append(diagramVar)

self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
self.validate.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

> Q: For the moment i just want to print the state of each checkbuttons
>   when i push the validate button but my next step is for example if i
>   have self.diagramVars = [1, 0, 0] so the first checkButton is checked
>   and so i want to run another function with the name (or the text) of
>   the checked checkButton in paramater i don't know if i'm clear ?

I believe that this for loop which creates a dictionary with the `element` as the key will be a suitable solution (if `element` is able to be used as `text=element` option then it should be fine to be used as a key):

```py
self.diagramVars = {}

for element in self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams :
    diagramVar = IntVar()
    diagram = Checkbutton(self.window, text=element, variable=diagramVar, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    diagram.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    self.diagramVars[element] = diagramVar

self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
self.validate.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

When you create this dictionary, to retrieve the value of a CheckButton, you will use the line `diagramVars[element].get()` this will access the "real time" state of the `CheckButton`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm trying instead of creating a list to create a dictionnary like this : `diagramVars= {self.diagramVar : element}` or `diagramVars= {element : self.diagramVar}` but in both case i have an error.

Comment: How would you expect to pull a `CheckButton` element from this dictionary? Like how do you want to access a specific check button, because right now I don't have the full context of the reason you need a dictionary.

Comment: For the moment i just want to print the state of each checkbuttons when i push the `validate button` but my next step is for example if i have `self.diagramVars = [1, 0, 0]` so the first checkButton is checked and so i want to run another function with the name (or the text) of the checked checkButton in paramater i don't know if i'm clear ?

Comment: I edited my answer and added a solution to this I believe.

Comment: That's the solution thanks ! The problem is `diagramVar` of each checkbuttons are always equal to 0 even if checkbuttons are checked or not

Comment: Wait, sorry I'm confused, did I solve the problem, or is there still the problem "`diagramVar` of each checkbuttons are always equal to 0 even if checkbuttons are checked or not"

Comment: You solve the problem about the dictionnary but i didn't notice at the beginning that with your solution even if i check any CheckButtons in the List (or in the dictionnary) `diagramVar`is still equal to 0. When i print the dictionnary with buttons checked and not checked i have this : `{'[LAB] Logical System 2': 0, '[LAB] Logical System': 0}
{'[LAB] Logical System 2': 0, '[LAB] Logical System': 0}`

Comment: Both code examples here are still using `variable=self.diagramVar` when creating the Checkbutton, even though that's not the var that's actually being added to the list or dict...

Comment: @Lucas `diagramVar` should not be an `int` value tho? it should be a pointer to the `IntVar` object, and you should be able to use the `.get()` method to get the value of the `checkButton`

Comment: @jasonharper ah yes you're right, I just overlooked removing `self.` from there. Thanks for the pickup! fixed that now

Comment: @MatthewG Yes i already did this `self.diagramVars[element] = diagramVar.get()` to verify if it is checked or not

Comment: @Lucas No, that's the issue, when you do that, you are setting the `self.diagramVars[element]` to the int of when the CheckButton is created, basically you are doing this `self.diagramVars[element] = 0`, because the dragramVars initial value is 0

Comment: @Lucas you want to do this `self.diagramVars[element] = diagramVar` and then when you want to retrieve the value of the checkbox you do this `self.diagramVars[element].get()` and that will give you the current state of the checkbutton

Comment: @MatthewG hmm so i don't get how to access to the value of the checkbutton "in real time" if i can say that

Comment: Using `self.diagramVars[element] = diagramVar` to assign the dictionary value, and `self.diagramVars[element].get()` to retrieve the dictionary value would make it an access of the "real time" value

Comment: Ok i get it ! Thanks a lot !